# Julia @everywhere importall confusing behaviour

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I'm trying to make some imported function available on all processes.

```
module EverywhereTest
@everywhere importall SubTest

function output()
    test_print()
end

end


module SubTest

export test_print

function test_print()
  print("hello")
end

end
```

On one process, this works without the `@everywhere`

```
using EverywhereTest
EverywhereTest.output()
hello
```

But with `@everywhere` I get `UndefVarError: test_print not defined`. Same behaviour with `using` instead of `importall`.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: You want to define the module to not be something parallel here, but import it everywhere. Remove your current `@everywhere` and instead do `@everywhere using EverywhereTest`. It's something that should be done at runtime, not compile time which can happen with a module (if you `__precompile__()`), and should be in the highest scope.

Comment: Thanks. I had in mind that EverywhereTest would be a master module farming out simulations to be run in parallel by SubTest, so I thought that EverywhereTest would only need to be available on one core. But you're saying I need to @everywhere everything?

Incidentally, I wasn't using `__precompile__()`